# Drupal creating a download link for video stream?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

using Drupal 7 and MediaFront, how can I go about creating a download link for a video that's currently being viewed?  What if I also want to offer the audio of the video as MP3? (Something that will be uploaded along with the video so no conversion is needed)

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https://drupal.org/project/file_force ? I haven't used it, but looks promising.

Or you you can try [file_transfer()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_transfer/7) with Content-Disposition header set as attachment.